# PHP urlencode() tacking on ?SID=xxx ... Why?

Tags: php, session, urlencode

I am trying to output a simple link.

This works great:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
echo $url;
```

This doesn't work great:

```
$url = 'http://www.google.com';
echo urlencode($url);
```

The second example tacks on "?SID=xxx" to the end of the URL for some reason. How do I prevent this from happening?

Note: The code to generate the URL has been changed to protect the innocent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use urlencode() to encode URL, you will end up an URL like this,

> http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com

To PHP, this looks like a relative URL so it appends SID when cookie is missing.

urlencode() should be used to encode query string parameters but not the URL itself.

Comment: That's the trick. This IS a query parameter for a facebook like button.

Answer (score 1):

This is not `urlencode()`s fault, it's PHP's automatic link rewriting that adds the session ID through a GET variable in absence of a session cookie.

I'm afraid this is necessary to persist sessions on the client side if they have cookies disabled.

The setting to do this automatically is `session.use_trans_sid`. More info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php).